# angular routing not working when using url in browser

Tags: angular, routes

```
 <span class="menu-link"[routerLink]="['/']">Home</span>
   <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" *ngIf="isUserAdmin">Admin</button> 
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['./admin/nomination-list']">Nomination(s) View</button>
  </mat-menu>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1"  *ngIf="this.Enable">Points</button>
  <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['./points/recognitionactivity']">Recognition Activity</button>
  </mat-menu>
```

above is my code for navigation page

when i navigate from navmenu link, all the url's are working fine but when i just use the url in the browser it is not working, even if refresh the page, page is not rendering. I notice some errors in console page but couldnt make much of it.

[image: works fine]

after refersh shows like this

[image]

getting below errors in console page

[image]

App routing module

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/home',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  canActivate: ['authGuard'],
  canActivateChild: ['authGuard']
},
{
  path: 'nav-menu',
  component: NavMenuComponent,
  canActivate: ['authGuard'],
  canActivateChild: ['authGuard']
},
{
  path: 'home',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: ['authGuard'],
  canActivateChild: ['authGuard']
 },
{
  path: 'admin/nomination-list',
  component: NominationListAdminComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full',
  canActivate: ['authGuardAdmin'],
  canActivateChild: ['authGuardAdmin']
},
{
  path: 'points/recognitionactivity',
  component: RecognitionsActivityComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full',
  canActivate: ['authGuardAdmin'],
  canActivateChild: ['authGuardAdmin']
},
{ path: 'silentauth', component: SilentAuthComponent, canActivate: [ 'authGuard' ] },

{path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
 ];

 @NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: false, enableTracing: false })],
 exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule {
 }
```

Comment: Try `routerLink="/points/recognitionactivity"` instead of the `[routerLink]="['./points/recognitionactivity']`  and routerLink="/". Also, make sure to add space between class and routerlink like exp: `class="menu-link" routerLink='/'`

Comment: why canActivate: ['authGuard'], canActivateChild: ['authGuard'] guards in string, it should be like canActivate: [authGuard], canActivateChild: [authGuard] in every route.